# Laravel - Factory seeding unique data on pivot table

Tags: laravel

```
Event::factory(5)
    ->hasAttached(
        Team::factory()->count($this->faker()->numberBetween(0, 60)),
        [
            'team_name' => $this->faker()->unique()->name,
            'score' => $this->faker()->numberBetween(0, 50)
        ],
        'participants'
    )
    ->create([
        'user_id' => $user,
        'quiz_id' => $quiz
    ]);
```

The above snippet of code creates 5 events for said `$user` using said `$quiz`. It will have a random amount of `participants` which is a pivot table (`Team` and `Event`). On that pivot table there is a `team_name` and `score` column. Because teams can change their team name we  want to know the team name at the time of participating and also the score in which they got for the event.

With the current code, because `$this->faker()->numberBetween(0, 60)`, `$this->faker()->unique()->name` and `$this->faker()->numberBetween(0, 50)` are not evaluated within an iteration, all the pivot table data is the same.

How can I make this data different per pivot row?

TIA

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out;

```
Event::factory(5)
    ->hasAttached(
        Team::factory()->count($this->faker()->numberBetween(0, 60)),
        function() {
            return [
                'team_name' => $this->faker()->unique()->name,
                'score' => $this->faker()->numberBetween(0, 50)
            ];
        },
        'participants'
    )
    ->create([
        'user_id' => $user,
        'quiz_id' => $quiz
    ]);
```